# Marketing Cloud: Error: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint. Cannot insert duplicate key in object

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, error, sql

Everyday we have an automation running to import new magento customers from an FTP file to our contact DataBase.
Today, for the first time we had this error message.

> Query failed during execution. Error: Violation of PRIMARY KEY
>   constraint. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'SystemData'. The
>   duplicate key value is ([HIDEN EMAIL]@gmail.com).

And this is the query :

```
select
s.Magento_ID as Magento_ID,
case
when r.[Marketing Cloud_ID] is null or r.[Marketing Cloud_ID] = '' then s.EmailAddress 
else r.[Marketing Cloud_ID] end as [Marketing Cloud_ID],
s.EmailAddress as Email
from Import_Magento_Account_All s
left join SystemData r
on
s.Magento_ID = r.Magento_ID
```

Is checked and the supposed duplicated email is not in our data model.
I'm really stuck any help will be much appreciated

Thank you!

Comment: what are the primary keys in your target DE?

Comment: Hi, 
It's the Marketing Cloud_ID wich actually is the email

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know you said there are no duplicate emails, but it might be best to set up a dedupe subquery to validate this:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM (
    select
    s.Magento_ID as Magento_ID,
    case
    when r.[Marketing Cloud_ID] is null or r.[Marketing Cloud_ID] = '' then s.EmailAddress 
    else r.[Marketing Cloud_ID] end as [Marketing Cloud_ID],
    s.EmailAddress as Email,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY s.EmailAddress ORDER BY s.EmailAddress) AS rn
    from Import_Magento_Account_All s
    left join SystemData r
    on
    s.Magento_ID = r.Magento_ID
) a
WHERE a.rn = 1
```

The above will only pull records where the email address exists once. As from your comment, I am assuming the Marketing_Cloud_ID is only emails currently, this should resolve the issue.

Comment: Thank you for your help.
When I add the updated code and click on the Check synthax  I have this error message :
An error occurred while checking the query syntax. Errors: The function 'ROW_NUMBER' must have an OVER clause with ORDER BY.

Comment: oh sugar, my bad. Will edit my answer

Comment: Thanks a lot! The synthax is ok now. I'll run my test in a test Data Extension to check if it fix the problem.

Comment: It worked! \o/ Thank you